# Asset fingerprinting in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, cdn

Rails provides a really simple solution for fingerprinting static assets. Is there anything similar available for the Play Framework? Can't seem to find anything on Google.

Thanks.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Update: My company ended up implementing one internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Play 2.3](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Highlights23) (currently on RC1) introduces a Rails-like asset pipeline with support for [asset fingerprinting](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets).

Comment: Play 2.3 has now been released. :)

Answer (score 3):

you may want to take a look at the new require.js support[1], available on play 2.1 master

[1] https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/e3c2ffb0d4779863374c44c5ec1a588a1eca4474

Comment: Hmm, we are currently using require.js to load assets in our play.1x app. Does using the require.js optimizer fingerprint the javascript file?

Answer (score 1):

Play framework 2 has built-in support for [CofeeScript](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/AssetsCoffeeScript), [LESS](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/AssetsLess) and [Closure](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/AssetsGoogleClosureCompiler), however none of them are considered as 'static' resources as they are compiled at the runtime.

There is no equivalent of `fingerprint` yet, so you'll need to write (probably quite short) action by yourself.

Comment: I mean static in the sense that they don't change on a per user basis. They are static content that can take advantage of a CDN for optimization, fingerprinting helps to make sure CDNs access the newest version of these files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you could do this through a quite short action as one answer mentions.

But you could create a wrapped Assets controller like James Ward does here:
https://github.com/jamesward/play2-cloudfront

That will just handle decorating the links with CDN information.  You could then get an MD5 of the link and append that to the file name.  So if you had foo.js it will be come foo-fp-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.js".

I think you would then have to change the routes file to route that asset to the right file when the CDN comes looking for it.  So the route would have to strip everything in "-fp-XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" and get the filename and extension.

EDIT:
  Here is git repo where I have an example of how we do asset fingerprinting at my company.  https://github.com/Egraphs/play-assets-improvements

Comment: Since posting this answer I've actually done this and it's working well.